# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a car-game project build with unreal engine 4.26, visual studio 2019 pro on win10.
However every time I try to build my project, it yeilds error:

> 1>C:\CTS6\Source\CarSimulation\SpeechEngine.cpp(11): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h': No such file or directory

Here is my code:

```
#include "SpeechEngine.h"
#include "SaHinhType.h"
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>


#include <sapi.h>
#include <minwindef.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <sphelper.h>


using namespace std;

ISpVoice *voice;
CComPtr<IEnumSpObjectTokens> cpEnum;
CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> cpVoiceToken;
SpeechEngine *SpeechEngine::instance = nullptr;
```

I've searched around but these suggestion do not solve my problem.
I've install VS Pro from official online installer and I've ticked all 'atl' related components.
[Image of installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9rbJ.png)